# How to run function when user swipe screen flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to use part of my code that  start when user click button on screen ,when he swipes screen to the left. It should work like when user swipe screen to flip the page in books app.

I tried GestureDetector but didn't found anything looks like what i want

I have a few widgets in column, code of widget that i show takes up most of screen

```
Expanded(
              flex: 7,
              child: GestureDetector(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  child: Html(
                      data:
                          "<p>${CheckList
                        .checkLists[widget.index]
                        .checkListPoints[
                            CheckList.checkLists[widget.index].position]
                        .requirement}</p>")),
              )),
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [page_turn](https://pub.dev/packages/page_turn)

or [better_page_turn](https://pub.dev/packages/better_page_turn)

better_page_turn is null safe and page_turn is from flutter community but not null safe